# Move build project from AWS code pipeline to TeamCity

Tags: java, jenkins, teamcity, cicd, migrating

CICD is happening in AWS code pipeline (via jenkins) and there are many project and i want to move all those project into TeamCity CI. How can i do? Kindly suggest me.

Code is building through AWS code pipeline which is also include code commit, and code deploy. I need to migrate everything like code commit to github, project from aws code pipeline to TeamCity/Octopus deploy server.

How can go through it. Kindly suggest. Thakns

Comment: We are building project through aws codepipeline and need to migrate into TeamCity CI tool

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.